# react component method execute order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a React beginner and trying to write a simple express-react stock chart app and there are two functions in the react app.js. One is to fetch data and the other is just to plot data. Here is the simplified code:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    seriesOptions: []
  }

  fetchData =(symbol)=>{
    var url = 'someurl'
    var that = this
    xhr({
      url: url
    }, function(e,d){
        if(e) {console.log(e);}
       else {
         var seriesOptions = 'some operation to calculate'
         that.setState({seriesOptions})
       }
    });
  }

  createChart=()=>{
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
      series: this.state.seriesOptions,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData('some stock symbol');
    this.createChart();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="container"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

 export default App;
```

What `seriesOptions` does is just to store the data fetched from database and `setState`. I looked into the console logs and found the difference is that createChart was called before fetchData even though in the code fetchData is prior.
Then I tried to call createChart inside `fetchData`, it works!
So I wonder how can I change the code and still can call createChart independently. 
Also, I want to know the root cause of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two lines are the key of everything.

```
this.fetchData('some stock symbol');
this.createChart();
```

What newcomers could think is that when the second line is executed, the first line has done all its job. But it's not the case. This because the only thing your first line do for sure before the second line is starting the ajax call. Then, this is an asynchronous call, so the execution proceed with the second line and you don't know when the first line will finish its work. At some point the ajax call receive its response and eventually set the state.

Comment: Thank you! I promisified fetchData and it works now. 
And is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You could call `createChart` after the `setState`. And not in the next line, because that's asynchronous too, but in this way `that.setState({seriesOptions}, that.createChart)`, passing a callback

Answer (score 0):

It because the `xhr()` function is asynchronous, in that it performs its logic on a separate thread before calling your passed-in function.

So if you were to say, add a log function on the first line of `fetchData()` you'd see that it executes first, but the `xhr()` call, being asynchronous runs on another thread, allows execution to continue on the first (and letting `this.createChart()` run).